# What are the differences between the apparent "profiles" of the K runtime?

Tags: asp.net-core

After setting up the [KRuntime](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki#runtime) [Version Manager](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager) and piddling around with the `kvm` command, it became apparent that there are two "profiles", so to speak, of the runtime:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> kvm list

Active Version      Runtime Architecture Location                             Alias
------ -------      ------- ------------ --------                             -----
       1.0.0-alpha3 svr50   x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages default
       1.0.0-alpha3 svrc50  x86          C:\Users\Administrator\.kre\packages
```

This seems reminicent of the .NET Framework's Client Profile, designed for phones and such and now obsoleted in .NET 4.5+.  Are `svr` and `svrc` built in a similar vein, or is there some other distinction?  There doesn't appear to be any reference to these versions of the runtime in the [aspnet's GitHub wiki](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aspnet team is working to rename svr50 and svrc50 for the alpha4 release of vNext. The new names will be CLR for svr50 and CoreCLR for svrc50. See [this GitHub issue and related commits](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/issues/598). The CoreCLR represents a sub-set of the respective framework version optimized to run in the cloud. The CoreCLR started in the Silverlight world, where it was built to be small, cross platform, and highly portable. The coreclr.dll is currently about 4MB big.

They recently [started work on adding friendlier names](https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/blob/5682674b2a164820e28cd41dfaded2b675a0962c/src/Microsoft.Framework.Runtime/FrameworkReferenceResolver.cs#L57-L80) to the target platforms. K10 was/is a working name for the ".NET Core Framework 4.5", aspnetcore50 is a friendly name for "ASP.NET Core 5.0", and aspnet50 for "ASP.NET 5.0".

These new ASP.NET target platforms are compatible with net45, but a regular net45 library isn't compatible with it.

Hope that clears it up a little bit more. vNext is still in alpha, so names are still subject to change, and many names are still work in progress.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer after all.  Turns out I just missed a [brief couple of sentences](https://github.com/aspnet/home#switching-to-core-clr) about it on the page describing the runtime:

> Run kvm install 1.0.0-alpha3 -svrc50 This command gets the latest Core
>   CLR version of the k runtime and sets it as your default. The -svrc50
>   switch tells it to use Core CLR. You can use -svr50 to target desktop
>   again.

So, to summarize: `svr50` is the desktop .NET framework, and `svrc50` is the new CoreCLR represented by the `k10` moniker in `project.json` files.  I'd still welcome an edit or a comment explaining the naming there, both the "svr/svrc" and numeric parts.  Clarification about `aspnetcore50` andd/or `aspnet50` would also be welcome.